# Sourcing low torque/small stepper motors

Tags: stepper-motor, motor

I am looking for some small and cheap stepper motors with <10oz-in torque. Most of the steppers I can find from my regular sources/ebay are 60-1000oz-in which is far too much for my purposes (and will almost certainly push the cost up). Does anyone know of a good source for these types of motors ? Unfortunately I would like 6 (and potentially more) of them, so scrounging from old floppy drives is not really an option.

Comment: production, or fun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this one from Adafruit?

http://www.adafruit.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=168

- 48 steps per revolution
- 5-12V DC
- Weight: 77 g.
- Holding Torque: up to 27 mNm / 3.75 oz-in

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea what torque a **wall clock mechanism** has, but I guess it will be rather low-ish. Prices equally low (from $5).

Comment: of wall clocks I've seen that have that twitchy second-hand effect suggestive of stepping, I don't recall one that didn't employ a small solenoid type device instead of a motor.